# Use variables in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php

I use a foreach loop in php to fill a table, after that I use `id` and `data-id to` work with the line of the table.

The problem is that I can't figured how to increment a variable during the loop and add it in the `id` like this :

```
id='addr0' data-id="0", 
id='addr1' data-id="1"
// etc.
```

Here is my loop :

```
foreach($result as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr id='addr0' data-id="0">  
        <td><?php echo $value['Nom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Prenom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Adresse']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Date de naissance']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Numero de telephone']; ?></td>
        <td data-name="del">
         <button nam"del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Probably `$key` is already a number incrementing from 0…? And if not… `$counter = 0`, `$counter++`…!?

Comment: Google `$i++`, that is the common solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is no code given to increment and output a variable

Comment: Also note that `<button nam"del0"` probably won't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($result as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr id='addr<?php echo $counter?>' data-id="<?php echo $counter?>">  
        <td><?php echo $value['Nom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Prenom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Adresse']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Date de naissance']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Numero de telephone']; ?></td>
        <td data-name="del">
         <button name = "del<?php echo $counter?>" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
$counter++;
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: it work ! thanks dude, i was trying for 1 hour without results. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can get auto increment in two way.

Case 1 : If your $result is indexed array.

```
foreach($result as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr id="addr<?php echo $key ?>" data-id="<?php echo $key ?>">  
        <td><?php echo $value['Nom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Prenom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Adresse']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Date de naissance']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Numero de telephone']; ?></td>
        <td data-name="del">
         <button nam"del<?php echo $key ?>" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
        </td>
    </tr> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Case 2 : If your $result is associative array.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr id="addr<?php echo $i ?>" data-id="<?php echo $i ?>">  
        <td><?php echo $value['Nom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Prenom']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Adresse']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Date de naissance']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Numero de telephone']; ?></td>
        <td data-name="del">
         <button nam"del<?php echo $i ?>" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
$i++;
endforeach; 
?>
```